# How to navigate to other screen using the headerRight on the navigator code?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

The title is very confusing, but the explanation that I will give will be more clear.
I am creating one **StackNavigator** for my app, and I am defining one icon to be displayed on the header of one of my screens like so:

```
const navigator= createStackNavigator(
  {
    Initial: {
      screen: Posts,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "All Posts",
        headerRight: () => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ padding: 5 }}>
              <Feather name={"plus"} size={30} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        },
      },
    },
    Details: Details,
    Create: Create,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Initial",
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(navigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

The problem is that I want to navigate the user to the *Create* screen when the user presses the icon that I am rendering on the right side of the header, but I do not know how to have access to the *navigation.navigate()* function that the navigator generates for all the screens. I know that I can define the header on the Posts' screen file, so I have access to the *navigation.navigate()* function, but I want to know if there is some way to do it on the *App.js* file.

**EDIT**

Reading the documentation I saw that the way that I am was creating the navigator is not what the official documentation recommends. I learned to make it like this by one old course, using React Navigation 4.x, and now with React Navigation 6.x I perceived the difference in the creation and changed the way that I was doing it on my app. You can check the documentation for the problem that I was having [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options)

Comment: I think **App.js** file is the just entry point and it points to your **navigator file** where you declared the whole flow of navigation.

Comment: @SiddharthPatel, check the Niranjan answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare your navigation option this way by sending props

```
    options={(props) => ({
headerRight: () =>  <TouchableOpacity 
             onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate('Screen')} style={{ padding: 5 }}>
                  <Feather name={"plus"} size={30} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              })}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me why the function inside the options object has the parenthesis before the curly brackets? (props) => ({...})

Comment: simply because using parenthesis will directly return headerRight while if I hadn't use parenthesis I should be returning it.

If you omit the parenthesis, the arrow function has a concise body, which consists solely of a single expression whose result will implicitly become the return value of the function.